# How to calculate molar concentration from equilibrium equations with no initial concentration given

Tags: equilibrium, atmospheric-chemistry, geochemistry

Consider the following equations:

\begin{align}
\tag{1} 
  \ce{CO2 (g) + H2O (l) &<=> H2CO3 (aq)} &
  K_\ce{CO2} &= 10^{-1.47}\\
\tag{2}
  \ce{H2CO3 (aq) &<=> H+ (aq) + HCO^-_3 (aq)} &
  K_1 &= 10^{-6.35}\\
\tag{3} 
  \ce{HCO^-_3 (aq) &<=> H+ (aq) + CO^-_3 (aq)} &
  K_2 &= 10^{-10.33}
\end{align}

I am also told atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ is at $\pu{10^{-3.5} atm}$ and the solution is pure water.

So far I have been able to find the equilibrium equations and have got the concentration of $\ce{H2CO3}$ to be $\pu{10^{-4.97}}$. However, from this I do not know where to go in order to find the concentration of bicarbonate.